# Spring boot Foreign key constraint fails

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, foreign-keys

so I have a class Observer which needs to have a list of notifications I am using a OneToMany relation between the two classes, but for some reason when I want to insert a notification I get a foreign key constraint failure. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me or point me in the right direction, Thanks in advance

Observer class

```kotlin
@Entity
abstract class Observer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    open var id: Long = -1;
    @OneToMany
    open var notifications: MutableList<Notification> = mutableListOf()
    abstract fun update(podcast: Podcast);
}
// different file
@Entity
class User(
    var name: String,
    var password: String,
    @OneToMany
    var podcasts : MutableList<PodcastInfo> = mutableListOf(),
) : Observer() {
    override fun update(podcast: Podcast) {
        val notification = Notification(message = "There is a new episode of ${podcast.name}");
        this.notifications.add(notification)
        print("new episode for podcast ${podcast.name}")
    }
}
```

Notification class

```kotlin
@Entity
class Notification(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id : Long = -1,
    val date : LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    val seen : Boolean = false,
    val message: String
) {
}
```

The project is about podcasts and when a new episode is added I want to notify the observers

```kotlin
fun addEpisode(@ModelAttribute episodeRequest : EpisodeRequest, @PathVariable("id") id: Long) : String {
    ....
    podcast.addEpisode(episode); // this line adds the notification to the observer
    podcast.updateObservers(observerService)
    ...
}
 // different file    
fun updateObservers(observerService: ObserverService){
    this.observers.forEach{observer -> observerService.updateObserver(observer)  }
}

// different file, this is the only descendant of the observer class
fun updateObserver(observer: Observer) : Observer{
    val notifications = mutableListOf<Notification>()
    for (notification: Notification in observer.notifications){
        notifications.add(notificationService.update(notification))
    }
    observer.notifications = notifications;
    return observerService.save(observer)
}
// different file
fun update(notification: Notification) : Notification {
    return notificationRepository.save(notification) // this line throws the error
}
```

So I thought since I am first inserting/updating the notifications and then updating the observer class, I wouldn't get the foreign key error since the notifications would have valid id's.

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`podcasts`.`observer_notifications`, CONSTRAINT `FKgw8m1isyux27iyu8m0l57kdd6` FOREIGN KEY (`notifications_id`) REFERENCES `notification` (`id`))

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)`, so that notifications are flushed properly before the observer, or you invoke `notificationRepository.flush()` right after saving the notifications e.g. use:

```kotlin
fun updateObserver(observer: Observer) : Observer{
    val notifications = mutableListOf<Notification>()
    for (notification: Notification in observer.notifications){
        notifications.add(notificationService.update(notification))
    }

    entityManager.flush(); // <--- This here

    observer.notifications = notifications;
    return observerService.save(observer)
}
```